# Is it possible to use JavaScript to submit an unnamed form from outside an iFrame?

Tags: javascript, html

I know that may sound silly, but I'm trying to submit a form on a page inside an iFrame, from the parent site.

Here's an example of the form:

```
        <form action="/add_email" method="post"> 
        <div class="field"> 
            <label for="newEmailAddress" style="width: auto">Add new email address</label> 
            <input type="text" id="newEmailAddress" name="email" value="null" class="text-field" /> 
            <input type="hidden" name="__app_key" value="null"/> 
            <input type="submit" value="Add address and send activation email"> 
        </div> 
        </form>
```

As you can see, the Submit button, and the form itself both lack a proper name or id, this is not something I have control over. (It's on an external website.)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is an external website — no. The [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) prevents it.

**If** it was the same website then you could [communicate across frames](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/#frameRef) and then access the form via its numerical index in the [forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.forms) object (but you would also likely be able to give it an id and use that instead).

Comment: Hmm, is it only Mozilla-based browsers that prohibit this?

Comment: No, this is pretty cross-browser consistent, apparently for security reasons.

Comment: Understandable. Thanks for your help David.

Comment: Most definitely for security reasons. Create a hidden iframe, load a website into it, access the forms in it with JavaScript, read off the username and password that the browser inserts automatically. (For one simple example of why it would be a terrible idea to allow this).

Answer (score 1):

When no name is given to the form then form has the default form name in a form of array
ie form[]

hence one can create as many forms in script, the default name's index will increase.
Hence one can use it accordingly.